# Why installation of dbt fails? - Failed building wheel for tree-sitter

Tags: dbt

I'm trying to install dbt tool to Window 10. There is Python 3.9 and also VS2019 installed.(I don't know why required)

I'm getting strange errors and wondering errors and what should be done:

Command:

```
git clone https://github.com/fishtown-analytics/dbt.git
cd dbt
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Error:

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\my.name\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 
 'c:\users\my.name\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site- 
packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' build_wheel 
 'C:\Users\MY~1.NAME\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpzybnxyld'
       cwd: C:\Users\my.name\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-l8pl5jty\tree- 
 sitter_f257da752ba04b9dacbc947d2d743146
  Complete output (10 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tree_sitter
  copying tree_sitter\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\tree_sitter
  running build_ext
  building 'tree_sitter.binding' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build 
  Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for tree-sitter
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current development version of dbt (`develop` branch, or installable as `v0.20.0rc1`) requires two new dependencies:

- `tree-sitter==0.19.0`
- `tree-sitter-jinja2==0.1.0a1`

The first of these, `tree-sitter`, requires you to have a C compiler installed on your system. Check out the related issue on GitHub: https://github.com/fishtown-analytics/dbt/issues/3433

We're going to think about how we can make this installation experience smoother. In the meantime, you can [install GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/binaries.html) and then try installing dbt from source again.

Comment: I have installed now installed Cygwin to Windows 10 with default Cygwin config. Tried to install dbt from source again but same errors happened.

Comment: What is version that do not require those dependencies?

Comment: You can install the latest stable version of dbt (v0.19.1) from PyPi or Homebrew, and it will not require those dependencies. We're also working to remove the C compiler requirement ahead of the final v0.20.0 release.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation for the time is to stick to the previous release (stable 0.19.0
at the time of this comment) since in this scenario it takes up a lot of time to install the dependencies and also because dbt is recommended to be installed not in the default python package, but ratter in a virtual env.

So, in short terms

```
pip install dbt==0.19.0
```